# Onload appending images from a for-loop into an element

Tags: javascript, php, image, scope, onload

I've got a question about calling the onload of an image in a for-loop. I did some research and found similar topics on this site, unfortunately I haven't found a solution which I understand and was able to run.

**Achieve:** Loading images from a directory and appending them after they have loaded into an element.

**What works?** Loading the images from a directory and appending them to an element.

**What doesn't work:** Appending the images after the onload function.

I do have an idea because of the topics i've seen when browsing this site. When I don't have the right scope for the onload in a for-loop, it will take the last value (that's what happened after some tests), so I need a function(?) to break free from the scope with the data that I need for the image(?).

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$images_array = glob("{$dir}/*.{jpg,png,gif,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
?>

var js_images_array = <?php echo json_encode($images_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); ?>;

for(var i = 0; i < js_images_array.length; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    (function(k){
        img.className += " grid-item";
        img.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('image_grid').appendChild(img);
        }
        img.src = js_images_array[k];
    })(i);
}
```

This loads the last image of my array into the selected element.

Any ideas, suggestions and/or improvents?

Comment: You've to pass `img` to the IIFE too. Or rather not to use the IIFE at all, declare the variables with `let` instead.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, after removing the IIFE and making the 'var img' -> 'let img', it showed the images on the page!